# How do I fire a LOCATION_CHANGE event for react-router-redux?

Tags: javascript, redux, react-router, react-router-redux

According to [the documentation](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router-redux#what-if-i-want-to-issue-navigation-events-via-redux-actions) I should be able to fire a `LOCATION_CHANGE` event by calling `push('/with/the/path')`. Example from docs:

```
import { routerMiddleware, push } from 'react-router-redux'

// Apply the middleware to the store
const middleware = routerMiddleware(browserHistory)
const store = createStore(
  reducers,
  applyMiddleware(middleware)
)

// Dispatch from anywhere like normal.
store.dispatch(push('/foo'))
```

However, this looks like when I call push I'm getting this (which doesn't look like it's doing anything):

[image]

**What am I missing?**

Comment: The `push` helper method is exactly for this purpose. What is your use case for trying to fire it manually? Maybe there are internals that are wrapped by the push method you can not otherwise invoke.

Comment: did you `syncHistoryWithStore`?

Comment: @MarioTacke I am trying to redirect to another part of the app. (i.e. "/profile")

Comment: @xiaofan2406 I did. :(

Comment: Like xiaofan2406 suggested, make sure to sync your history. Can you edit your question with your *full* store setup? As it stands, it does not look like you set up the syncing correctly.

Comment: @MarioTacke I forgot to apply the routerMiddleware. :s If you will post an answer I will mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure to sync your history with your store. The following is an example setup:

```
import { routerMiddleware, syncHistoryWithStore, push } from 'react-router-redux'

// Apply the middleware to the store
const router = routerMiddleware(browserHistory)
const store = createStore(
  reducers,
  applyMiddleware(router)
)
const history = syncHistoryWithStore(browserHistory, store)

// Dispatch from anywhere like normal.
store.dispatch(push('/foo'))
```

Notice the bit about `syncHistoryWithStore` *after* you create the store.

Hope this helps.